# open star set domain, show that $ u+iv $ is a holo

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ \Omega  \subset \mathbb{C} $ be a star-shaped domain with respect to the point $0$.
So for every point $p \in \Omega$, the line segment from $p$ to $0$ lies entirely inside of $\Omega$. Moreover $ u $ is a harmonic function in $ \Omega$ and $ v $ is a function in $ \Omega $ with:

$$ v(x,y) = \int_0^1 (yu_x(tx,ty) - xu_y(tx,ty)) dt $$

for $ z = x+iy $, $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Show that $ u + iv $ is holomorphic function in $ \Omega $.

**idea:**

So I don't have many tools for this, so I guess we need Cauchy-Riemann equations.

So we need $ u_x = v_y $ and $ u_y = - v_x $.

We know that $ u $ is harmonic, so we know that:

$ u_{xx} = -u_{yy} $

Now we consider:

$ v_y = \frac{d}{dy}\int_0^1 (yu_x(tx,ty) - xu_y(tx,ty)) dt $

and

$ - v_x = - \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^1 (yu_x(tx,ty) - xu_y(tx,ty)) dt $

I know it is not much, nevertheless I hope you can help.

Thank you in advance.